# Notes Replication error: You are not authorized to copy or replicate from this database

Tags: replication, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have been trying to create a local replica of one of the databases in Lotus Notes and getting the above stated error message.

I tried all the fix mentioned in various websites, making Anonymous access to replicate or copy documents, but with no success.

The lotus notes version is 6.5 and I am creating replica from client.

Comment: I've already answered, but just realized that this is not a programming question, so it might be more appropriate for SuperUser instead of StackOverflow.  It is, however, important for developers to understand the Notes security model, so I guess I'm not going to flag it.

Comment: in that case i will post the same question there. I am more of a programmer so dont have much knowledge of these admin terms, but i always try to learn as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Check all of the ACL entries.  There is a check-box for every entry labeled "Replicate or copy documents".  If it is not checked for the entry that applies to you, then you are not going to be allowed to replicate. Also, note that there is a very serious side-effect from this setting, which is described in this IBM [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21164209).   Even if you check the box for the ACL entry, you will still be prevented from replicating any document that was previoulsy created or edited by you or any other user who did not have the "Replicate or copy documents" permission.  (I consider this a design flaw in Domino, but IBM apparently disagrees.)

BTW: Anonymous access would not apply to you with the Notes client.  (Well, actually there are cases where it could, but it's unlikely this is one of them.  It applies only to public Domino servers that allow unauthenticated client connections, which are very rare.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved now:

The fix was:

There were more than 1 replica's on the same server under different folders out of which user did not had access to one of the replica. Deleting that replica did the trick.